# How is it possible that listening to Firestore collection allows to access data that I shouldn't have access to?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

## Given the below rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Nobody except superuser and member can see member data
    match /Member/{id} {
      allow get: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
      allow list: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
            //allow read: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
      allow update: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
      allow delete: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
      allow create: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));
        }
  }
}
```

## And my data: Member collection.

document ID: PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2 which has some fields
   document ID: QM6tGSkA2SRSPjHGIurDiARd6zv1 which has some fields

## My observations that make sense:

### 1) Using the Rules playground

```
Simulation type: get
Location: /Member/PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2
Authenticate: false
```

#### Result:

Simulated read denied, due to : "allow get: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));" This makes total sense.

### 2) Using the Rules playground

```
Simulation type: get
Location: /Member/PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2
Authenticate: true
Provider: Google
Firebase UID: QM6tGSkA2SRSPjHGIurDiARd6zv1
```

#### Result:

Simulated read denied, due to : "allow get: if ((request.auth != null) && (id == request.auth.uid));" This makes total sense.

### 3) Using the Rules playground

```
Simulation type: get
Location: /Member/PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2
Authenticate: true
Provider: Google
Firebase UID: PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2
```

#### Result:

Simulated read allowed. This makes total sense.

### 4) In flutter,

#### Codesnippet 1:

```
await AbstractRepositoryS
ingleton.singleton
    .userRepository()
    .signInWithGoogle()
    .then((value) async {
      await AbstractRepositorySingleton.singleton
          .memberRepository().valuesList().then((event) {
        print("Success");
      });
```

#### Codesnippet 2 (implementation of AbstractRepositorySingleton.singleton.memberRepository().valuesList())

```
  Future<List<MemberModel>> valuesList() async {
    return await MemberCollection.getDocuments().then((value) {
      var list = value.documents;
      return list.map((doc) => _populateDoc(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
```

#### Codesnippet 3:

```
final CollectionReference MemberCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('Member');
```

#### Action:

I run code snippet 1, which requests me to login onto my phone. I login with firebase UID = PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2, then a query for ALL members is run.

#### Result:

This fails, which ones again all makes sense.

## My observations that make NO sense:

#### Codesnippet 1:

```
await AbstractRepositorySingleton.singleton
    .userRepository()
    .signInWithGoogle()
    .then((value) async {
      await AbstractRepositorySingleton.singleton
          .memberRepository().values().listen((event) {
        print("Success");
      });
```

#### Codesnippet 2 (implementation of AbstractRepositorySingleton.singleton.memberRepository().values())

```
  Stream<List<MemberModel>> values() {
    return MemberCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
            .map((doc) => _populateDoc(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
```

#### Action:

I run code snippet 1, which requests me to login onto my phone, I login with user with firebase ID = PIijFvYPXQPSlheQxotvFvXW4VI2,
then a LISTEN for ALL members is executed.

#### Result

This succeeds and the _populateDoc allows me to read all data fields from all members.
Basically it seems this mechanism allows me to read the entire collection, even for data where I should have no access to.
However, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong... but what.
Please advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is an error occurring during the listen() method:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Still for some reason I had 4 hits in the breakpoint in _populateDoc where I could happily read the member data from the doc.

After given this a bit extra thoughts, I've come to the conclusion this might have to do with local caching of the firestore data on my phone.

So I tried another phone, one where this particular app never ran before, I got the same error and I had 1 hit in the breakpoint in _populateDoc.

It's starting to make a bit sense to me. However, if someone could confirm this. Is this somewhere documented?